# How to customize DatagridView in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

In datagridview, when we need to show value than it will display as below.

User 1

User 2

User 3

Now my requirement is that, say i have only single column and about 100 data.
I want to display as below.

User 1 User 4 User 7

User 2 User 5 User 8

User 3 User 6 User 9

Is it possible to this in c#.?

Comment: no, its not possible.

Comment: @Reniuz is there any other alternative.?

Comment: write your own control

Comment: Because of lack of details about your requirements and everything else..I just can say that you can use ListView.

Comment: Knowing absolutely nothing about your data, there is not much more we can say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create my new datatable with several columns.

Refer this link : [Datagrid: Break single column to multiple](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/874831-datagridview-multiple-columns)

Thanks to [GaryTexmo](http://bytes.com/profile/239261/garytexmo/)